# iOS app Launch Detection

Tags: objective-c, loops, detect, launch

I am trying to implement my app to do something every 3rd launch.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this instead of what I have done below...

```
NSUserDefaults *timesRan;
int launchCount;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    timesRan = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    launchCount = [timesRan integerForKey:@"hasRan"] + 1;
    [timesRan setInteger:launchCount forKey:@"hasRan"];
    [timesRan synchronize];



                    if(launchCount == 3) {
                       //Do something every 3rd launch
                    }

                    if(launchCount == 6) {
                        //Do something every 3rd launch
                    }


                    if(launchCount == 9) {
                        //Do something every 3rd launch
                    }

                    if(launchCount == 12) {
                        //Do something every 3rd launch
                    }

                    if(launchCount == 15) {
                        //Do something every 3rd launch
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be a better solution but still a better condition check.

Replace your `if` condition with

```
if (launchCount  == 3) // Use launchCount % 3 == 0 if not reseting counters
{
    launchCount = 0 //reset counter and synchronise.
    [timesRan setInteger:launchCount forKey:@"hasRan"];
    [timesRan synchronize];
    // Additional logic goes here to be done on third launch
}
```

And you might want to make use of [`applicationWillEnterForeground`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground:) as well.